# Using (non-localized) static final String server-side constants client-side

Tags: java, gwt

I am working with an application with a bunch of non-localized constants

> (most of them are 'static final String' put in a non-instancializable
>   class)

I would like to reference some of these constants from GWT client-side.

I had a "**MyAppConstants.java**" in **my.company.package**.
So I created a "`MyGwtConstants`" module in the **my.company.package** package, created a "`GwtConstants`" class there (`GwtConstants` package is part of the `MyGwtConstants` module source paths), moved some constants from `MyAppConstant` to `GwtConstants`, and made `MyAppConstants` inherit my `GwtConstants`. But this solutions sucks.

- Why should I modify existing code ? (`MyAppConstants.java`)
- What if I want to use client-side constants that came from server-side used libraries ?
  For instance, what if `MyAppConstants.java` contained a reference to `StringUtils.EMPTY` and I want to use that GWT client side ?
  I cannot reference StringUtils' EMPTY from GWT client layer, and I cannot afford to create a GWT module for each and every possible package referenced (here, this would require creating another GWT module under org.apache.commons.lang, because a module can only reference code contained in a subpackage, afaik source paths are relative, cannot be absolute).

There must be a simpler way to do this ? (the goal is obviously to avoid duplicate constants)

Comment: When would you need (or want) to have localized constants?

Comment: I don't need these constants localized, I just want to use them from GWT client side (without GWT compilation failing because it does not have the source for it. Compilation happens to work on my workstation, but I understand it should fail, and it fails when compiled with our continuous integration compilation, I think it is because GWT does not allow such external references - tell me if I'm wrong).
The many "public static final String" contants I have are non-GWT code used in non-GWT pages (but in the same web app / same Eclipse project, 'though some constants come from libraries).

Comment: I know. I was wondering what would be a situation where you *would* need localized constants. Unless you're talking about the constant values, but then they wouldn't really be constants.

Comment: Sorry I think my post was actually confusing.
Please read "I don't need these constants localized, I just want to use them from GWT client side", read "I don't need constants localized or need to reference them in any way, I just want to use existing static final primitive data types constants from GWT client side"

Comment: Why dont you move your `MyAppConstants.java` to `my.company.shared.package` so it can be accessed from client and server side? Only disadvantage would be that you couldnt use libs that are not supported by GWT client side. (but for example Guava GWT would work for client and server..)

Comment: Moving one or two files is easy, but I cannot afford to move many files to my.company.shared.package.
For instance, what if I want to use source currently shared with another project of mine through a jar file ? (I cannot and should not have to modify that other project)

Comment: IIRC gwt compiler can inline string constants (static final, but only string literal) from classes outside of "source" packages. But maybe gwt compiler are needed source code for java file with constants.